# Add HTML node programmatically with Angular 2 / Ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I'm new to Ionic 2 & Angular 2 and I would like to add button element programmatically (in TypeScript file).
For example this kind of node :

```
<button ion-button (click) = "self.showAlert('dynamic component')">DynamicComp</button>
```

How can I do that ? I've tried ComponentOutlet but it seems does not work....

Any ideas ?

Comment: What do you mean by programmatically? You want to insert that button?

Answer (score 2):

html:

```
<button ion-button (click) = "showAlert('dynamic component')">DynamicComp</button>
```

ts:

```
showAlert(message:string){
  alert(message);
}
```

Something like this?

Or if you want to add a button to your page throught TS -->

html

```
<div [innerHtml]="innerHtmlVar"></div>
```

ts

```
innerHtmlVar:string = `<button ion-button (click)="self.alert('message')"></button>`
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Indeed I want to insert that button so the second solution seems to be interesting. I'll test that

Comment: Not sure if it works with all the different types of quotes, maybe you should escape them, let me know if it doesn't work and I'll edit my answer

Comment: So I did the same thing than you, but added "TEST" to the button description so at the end of the line we've the following thing : `ssage')">TEST</button>`. Then, I see 'TEST' but directly wrote into my div. So it's not a button. It's maybe due to an escape problem ? Perhaps, I've showed in a log the result of `innerHtmlVar` and it seems to be correct : `<button ion-button (click)="self.alert('message')">TEST</button>`. I've my code into this gist : https://gist.github.com/CallisteHanriat/2d29aa38441f698d042220d885ad47d6

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, you cannot use innerHtml to insert any Angular-calling code like (click). innerHtml will only display html. In fact, by default it sanitizes (i.e., strips out) a lot of "unsafe" html, but with work you can turn off sanitization. But even then, you won't get Angular code like (click) working.

You need to use [ComponentOutlet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-component-outlet) if you want Angular behavior in your dynamic html. Here's a [working plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/RJbFzg?p=preview) the maintainer of that project wrote which shows using a custom tag inside a dynamic template. The key part is in file src/app.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <ng-container *componentOutlet="template; context: context"></ng-container>
    </div>
  `,
})
export class App {
  template = `<h2>Hello {{name}}</h2><page-component-test></page-component-test>`
  context = {
    name: 'Angular 2'
  }
}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App, ComponentOutlet ],
  providers: [provideComponentOutletModule({
    declarations:[PageComponentTest]
  })],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```